# ReactNative TextInput in Android is not editable

Tags: android, react-native

Below is the simple code I have.

```js
change(text) {
  this.setState({text});
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome, what is your name?
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, width: 200}}
        onChangeText={this.change.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

It works as expected in iOS. In Android, it shows the Text and TextInput field. However anything I type in TextInput does not show up.

I have two questions basically.

First one is, what might be going wrong here?

Second and more important question is, how do I debug a problem like this? I used ReactNative debugger and put a breakpoint in `change` function, it doesn't get called.

I also checked the generated native code in anticipation to debug using Android Studio. Didn't see anything in the code there where I can possibly put a breakpoint.

Comment: This code works for me. Did you get any sort of error  ?

Comment: @RoshanGautam no errors. If you don't mind, what version of react-native do you have? Mine is 0.48.4

Comment: I ran the above code in snack and it was working perfectly. So yes, 0.48.4.
Here is the link to the snack. 

https://snack.expo.io/S1bJx-o3b

Answer (score 0):

If in case it helps someone - here is what I found.

I was running Android emulator with API level 25 (Nougat).
When I switched to API level 23 (Marshmallow) it started working.